# update query to update max of id

Tags: mysql, sql-update

apologies if question is ambiguous. following is the scenario:

question master table:

```
id   No
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
```

question part table:

```
qid   statement
 1     abc
 2     xyz
 3     a1235
 4     abcde
 5     asdf
```

this data now needs to be imported into a new structure 
where only one qid should be present for each question no.

so in above example qid `1,2` should only be either 1 or 2 etc.

an trying to make an update query but it doesnt seem to do what exactly is needed.

the end result can be like so:

```
qid   statement
 1     abc
 1     xyz
 3     a1235
 4     abcde
 4     asdf
```

the query is as follows:

```
  update questionpart qp
set Q_ID =
(
select max(nq.Q_ID) FROM newquestion nq
where nq.Q_No = (select nq2.Q_No FROM newquestion nq2 where nq2.Q_ID = qp.Q_ID )
)
```

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an example of your desired end result.

Comment: @Carter thank you for the response. question has been updated :)

Answer (score -1):

```
update questionpart qp
    join newquestion nq on qp.Q_ID = nq.Q_ID
    set qp.Q_ID = nq.NO;
```

I believe this is what you are trying to do. ( Set the question part Q_ID to be the new question/master question Q_NO value. If this is not what you are looking for please provide the table schemas.

Comment: thank you for the answer . it helps somewhat as it assign question number  as q_id (i think :)  ) but the duplicate data issue still persists. what we wish to achieve is that assign any one  single id against the recurring question numbers and later delete from the master table the ids which are no longer being used. anyways . thank you for the time.